# Events not working after the page loads for the first time using jquery mobile

Tags: android, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using JQM 1.1.0 and Cordova 1.5.0.

I have code like this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Index Page</title>

<!-- Adding viewport -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />    
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Adding Phonegap scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"
src="cordova/cordova-1.5.0.js"></script>

<!-- Adding jQuery mobile and jQuery scripts & CSS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="jquerymobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="jquerymobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/colors.css">

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#page1").live("pageinit", function(e) {
console.log("pageinit1");
    }

$("#page2").live("pageinit", function(e) {
console.log("pageinit2");
    }
</script>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
  <div data-role="header">Page 1</div>
  <div data-role="content"></div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2">
  <div data-role="header">Page 2</div>
  <div data-role="content"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

This code is working fine for Android. but in iOS,as soon as the page loads then the pageinit event of page1 doesnt get fired and later on if i changepage to page2 then everything is fine.. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just need to write my javaScript functions after data-role="page" to make it working...

Answer (score 1):

am not so sure about that but as i know live function has changed in JQ1.7.x and now you will have to use the on() function which has small changes to the way you code your code ..